# Find the solution of this differential equation whose graph it is through the point $(1,3e)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let $y_{1} (x) = e^{x}$ and $y_{2} (x) = x^{2}+1+e^{x}$ be solutions of the differential equation $$a(x)y'  + b (x) y = c (x)$$, where a, b, c are continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ and the function $a$ has no zeros. Find the solution of this differential equation whose graph it is
through the point $(1,3e)$.

I know that difference between $y_{1}(x)$ and $y_{2}(x)$ is a solution of homogeneous differential equation. So solution of a homogeneous differential equation is $$y_{h}=A(x^{2}+1)$$.

I do not know how to get the particular solution. If I use variation constant for $y_{p}=z(x)(x^{2}+1)$, where is $z(x)$ a function, then I get $$z= \int\frac{c(x)}{a(x)}e^{\int\frac{b(x)}{a(x)}dx}dx$$

Any help?

Comment: Are you saying that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are particular solutions to your DE?

Comment: I think that are particular solutions

Comment: I believe you are given two of those..

Comment: What do you mean by that I am given two of those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general solution to a first-order DE is given by $y(x) = y_h(x) + y_p(x) = cg(x) + y_p(x)$, where $c$ is arbitrary and $g$ is a solution to the associated homogeneous equation. Since you know two solutions $y_1$ and $y_2$, the difference must be proportional to $g$, which means that $g(x) = x^2 + 1$ as you predicted. Moreover, this implies that the particular solution is $y_p(x) = e^x$. Thus, we have $y(x) = c(x^2 + 1) + e^x$ and you can now solve for the constant $c$ using the initial condition $y(1) = 3e$.

Comment: I do not understand, how did you get $y_{p} (x) =e^{x}$

Comment: @NikiSedlarević It's because we know that $y_h(x)$ is proportional to $x^2 + 1$ and $y(x) = c(x^2 + 1) + y_p(x)$.